# Need first and last day on a period datetime

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm working with Carbon Period to get intervals of 'N' days between two dates.

In a iterations for each period I need to know how to get first and last day of each period.

E.g:

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-10-01', '30 days', '2020-02-15');
// What I need is
// Period 1: from 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-31
// Period 2: from 2019-11-01 to 2019-11-30
// Period 3: from 2019-12-01 to 2019-12-31
// Period 4: from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31
// Period 5: from 2020-02-01 to 2020-02-15
```

Comment: And what about how to do that is still unclear, after you checked the documentation? https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Comment: of course I've read documentation. It's clear to make an interval between start and end dates but don't know how to get first and last day on each interval from start and end given dates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the beginning/ending date of each period, but you can use a copy/setter to get the next day of the end period.

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-10-01', '30 days', '2020-02-15');
$start = null;
foreach($period as $key=>$date) {
    if(!$start) {
        echo "Start 1 : ".$period->getStartDate()->toDateString(). " End : ".$date->toDateString()."\n";
        $start = $date->copy()->addDay();
    } else {
        echo "Start 2 : ".$start->toDateString(). " End : ".$date->toDateString()."\n";
    }
    $start = $date->copy()->addDay();
}
if($start->lt($period->getEndDate())) {
    echo "Start : ".$start->toDateString(). " End : ".$period->getEndDate()->toDateString()."\n";
}
//Start : 2019-10-01 End : 2019-10-01
//Start : 2019-10-02 End : 2019-10-31
//Start : 2019-11-01 End : 2019-11-30
//Start : 2019-12-01 End : 2019-12-30
//Start : 2019-12-31 End : 2020-01-29
//Start : 2020-01-30 End : 2020-02-15
```

Since 2020-01-30 - 2020-02-15 is not 30 days, it's not created as another interval. You have to manually check for that add it as in the last few lines, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `1 month` as interval instead of `30 days`:

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-10-01', '1 month', '2020-02-15');
```

Then you can use `endOfMonth()` method to get your expected result:

```php
$dates = [];

foreach ($period as $index => $date) {
    $dates[] = sprintf("Period %s: from %s to %s",
        $index + 1,
        $date->toDateString(),
        $period->getEndDate()->min($date->endOfMonth())->toDateString()
    );
}
```